# Configure Kate to build and execute a project

Tags: shortcut-keys, configuration, kate

I want Kate to run `make` when I hit `F9` and `./bin/exe` when I hit `F5`. Is that possible?

Edit: figured out the building part - there's a plugin for that. Now I want to execute what I built.

Answer (score 0):

There's a hack: activate the build plugin, set up a shortcut for it and insert an execution command in the makefile so it's built and run in the same operation.